# Avoid mobile devices responsiveness Wordpress Elementor

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, elementor

I have tried different solutions found in the web but with no success. I have tried already to remove the string from the file header.php but nothing happened.

The client wants the website to look exactly the same as the desktop version in all the mobile devices, so I have to delete what makes responsive my theme.

I'm using the theme "Twenty Twelve" from Wordpress and Elementor as visual editor.

Does anyone know how I can reproduce this? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `Viewport meta tag` from the header file check below

### `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Hi Aman, thanks for replying. I already did but nothing changes. I also accessed the file header.php through ftp in the theme folder and applied the change, but no differences!

Answer (score 0):

Change Mobile & Tablet Breakpoints
You can set the mobile and tablet breakpoint values.

Go to Elementor > Settings > Style Tab, and set the breakpoint value for mobile and tablet
Save your changes
Go to Elementor > Tools > General Tab > Regenerate CSS, click Regenerate Files

set the breakpoint value = 0

Comment: Hi there, thanks for replying. Unfortunately tried that too before, when I digit 0 after 2 seconds the value disappears and it shows the default value (mobile 798 and table 1025). It only allows me to insert a value between 440px to 798px for mobiles.

Comment: I also use an external plugin to edit the elementor breakpoints called "CUSTOM BREAKPOINTS FOR ELEMENTOR" and then regenerated the CSS but nothing happened.

Comment: is it necessary to use Elementor? what about the composer? Composer has an option to remove responsive completely

Answer (score 0):

change initial-scale=1.0 to initial-scale=0 in meta tag